# C - scanf doesn't stop looping in string input

Tags: c

i'm making a small test to see if a word is inside another, and i want to return the index where that word begins.

Example: if i check "um" inside "amolum" the return value should be 4(position of the leter "u" where the word begins.

This is what my code looks like:

```
(...)
int cad_look_str (char s1[], char s2[]) {
  int indS1 = 0, indS2 = 0;

  while (s1[indS1]!='\0'|| s2[indS2]!='\0') {
    if (s1[indS1]==s2[indS2]) {
      indS1++;
      indS2++;
    }
    else indS1=0;
  }

  if (s2[indS2]=='\0' && s1[indS1]!='\0') return -1;
  else return indS2-strlen (s1);
}


void main () {
  char s[100];
  char s1[100];

  scanf ("%s",s); 
  scanf ("%s",s1);

  printf ("%d \n", cad_look_str(s1,s) );
}
```

The problem is that when i compile this, it doesn't stop looping on scanf... It just continues to ask for strings.

If i put cad_look_str(s1,s1) on the last line, it works fine... Why is this happening?

Regards

Comment: You're forgetting to indS2++ in the else (otherwise you'll be stuck there forever)

Comment: @Inox yeap figured that out with the help of David :P Thanks

Comment: @Inox I am getting a segmentation fold if i test for example "dadada" in the word "gdgddadada"... any reason why?

Comment: I *Think* the problem now is that you find an *initial* match with the 'd' character in the 1 index position of 'gdgddadada', but the next index fails, so you should reset your target string index to 0 to ensure you restart the search at the beginning of the sought string...That is, once you've *started* a match, you have to be cognizant of it if that match *eventually* fails before comparing the entire string. Might need to add a bit of additional control logic there.

Comment: @DavidW yeah it helped. I've implemented a control if for that situations.

"        else if ( s1[0] == s2[indS2] ) {indS1=1; indS2++;}
             else{indS1=0; indS2++;}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed cad_look_str() for situations like s1 : gdgddadada, s2 : dadada

```
int cad_look_str (char s1[], char s2[]) {
  int indS1 = 0, indS2 = 0;
  int flag = 0;


  while (s1[indS1]!='\0'&& s2[indS2]!='\0') {
    if (s1[indS1]==s2[indS2]) {
      indS1++;
      indS2++;
      flag = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        indS1=0;
        indS2++;
        if(flag) indS2--; // to work with srtrings s1: gdgddadada s2: dadada
        flag = 0;
    }
  }

  if (s2[indS2]=='\0' && s1[indS1]!='\0') return -1;
  else return indS2-strlen (s1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your initial loop condition will never terminate if the first characters don't match your comparison test within your if statement.

The 'while' loop checks to ensure the current character positions (both 0 on first pass) are non-terminators. If they're not, and they're not equal, `indS1` is reset to its starting position. `indS2` never changes, thus the while condition is unchanged.

Might look at some other string functions to accomplish your task unless the scanning is a mandatory component for some reason.

Comment: Thanks! The else condition should increment indS2. It works now :P

Answer (score 2):

Index of second string should be incremented in the else part also.

```
if (s1[indS1]==s2[indS2])
{
        indS1++; indS2++;
}
else {
         indS1=0;
         indS2++;
}
```

Comment: I am getting a segmentation fold if i test for example "dadada" in the word "gdgddadada"

Comment: if s1 is longer than s2, incrementing the index indS2 will cause it to exceed the bounds of that array, traversing into unallocated territory and causing your segmentation fault.

Comment: hi @DavidW but this is not the case... dadada has 6 char that's less than the S2 word. I've tried "b" in "asf" it should return -1 right? it blows up too

Comment: Replace **while (s1[indS1]!='\0'|| s2[indS2]!='\0')** with **while (s1[indS1]!='\0'&& s2[indS2]!='\0')**

Comment: **Note:** first input string should be larger than the second input string(substring)